# why am i getting user bin error when following steps from cs50 video

Tags: cs50

My code attached
[week 1 cs50 - Minute 38](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGl81.png)
I'm really not sure why I'm getting this error I'm really struggling to find the answer any help is appreciated.

i have copied everything David Malan did in the video. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

[the error is also attached below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C275.png)
[CS50 video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diyGf.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things.  Instead of declaring your variable as a "string" you probably would want to declare it as a "char *" (e.g. char * answer) or char with a specific size allocation (e.g. char answer[32]).

You are indeed placing the input value into a string called "answer", but in your "printf" statement, the literal "answer" is just a word that is a part of a constant string you are printing out to your terminal.  What you would want to do is something like this:

```
char * answer = get_string("What is your name");
printf("Hello %s\n", answer);
```

Hope that helps.

Regards.

Comment: thank you very much this helped once again sorry for the newb question im just getting started.

Comment: Glad to help.  We all start out as beginners and then gain experience.